# c++ pass pointer between classes - access other class methods

Tags: c++

I have this class instance

```
ControlPanel *cp = new ControlPanel();
```

Another class needs access to the methods in cp so I

```
Monitor *cpmon = new Monitor(cp);
```

The Monitor class header looks like

```
class Monitor {
public:
    Monitor(ControlPanel *_cp);
    ~Monitor();
private:
    ControlPanel *cp;
}
```

and the Monitor constructor looks like

```
#include "Monitor.h"

Monitor::Monitor(ControlPanel *_cp)
    {
    *cp = _cp; //doesn't work
    }
```

error is :

> no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘ControlPanel’ and ‘ControlPanel*’)

now I printed the pointer addresses along the way and I can access the methods from within the constructor eg if I do _cp->SomeMethod it works but I don't know how I can code that the private *cp actually is the same address _cp points to so that I can access the cp intantiated at the very top from within Monitor's methods and not just from within its constructor - I read a lot - tried a zillion things, got a lot of different errors but I just can't make it work. Can someone clarify? How do I assign private *cp _cp's address please?
thank you

Comment: Why is not like _*cp=*_cp_   ?

Comment: I tried that previously and it compiles but segfaults

Comment: @ZoOl007 That' indicates a flaw in your `ControlPanl ` class then. Don't use raw pointers at all please unless you're absolutely sure you need them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you dereference the pointer and assign it to a pointer.  To fix, simply change from

```
*cp = _cp;
```

to

```
cp = _cp;
```

Comment: yes! I get it... everything points to the same address now... Thank you very much

Comment: I just ran a quick test and the program seems to behave as it should. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Either the ControlPanel must supply you with a assignment operator (a built-in assignment operator may do bitwise-copy and thus give you segfuault) OR you should start using just the pointers to ControlPanel (instead of copying the ControlPanel objects).

Both approaches have their advantages and disadvantages. If I have access to the source code of Control Panel, I would write a valid assignment operator (if it is required! Writing the special class functions in C++ must be done carefully in order to avoid surprises and painful troubleshotting later).